# int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import easygui
from random import randint

Minimum = easygui.enterbox(msg = "Choose your minimum number")
Maximum = easygui.enterbox(msg = "Choose your maximum number")
operator = easygui.enterbox(  msg="which operator would you like to use? X,/,+ or - ?",title="operator")
questions = easygui.enterbox(msg = "enter your desired amount of questions")

for a in range(int(questions)):
  rn1 = randint(int(Minimum), int(Maximum))
  rn2 = randint(int(Minimum), int(Maximum))
  answer = easygui.enterbox("%s %s %s =?" %(rn1, operator, rn2))
  realanswer = operator (int(rn1,rn2))
  if answer == realanswer:
   print "Correct"
  else:
   print 'Incorrect, the answer was' ,realanswer
```

When I try and run it, all the enterboxes come up fine, it is when it looks at line 13 that it produces this error:

> int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

I tried running the code without the `int()`, and then it gives me:

> 'str' object is not callable

Comment: `str is not callable` is because your operator is a string. In short, that's the next, unrelated bug you get after fixing this one. :)

Comment: Which is to say that if you get the `'str' object is not callable`, you've fixed the `int() can't convert non-string` bug, so you already know how to fix it, and don't need to ask a question here. :)

Comment: By the way -- for next time you're asking a question, try to isolate it down to only one thing. Including unnecessary dependencies such as the `easygui` library, for instance, makes it harder for folks to reproduce the problem -- and if you were _really_ only asking about the `int() can't convert non-string` question, you could have done that with only one line, something like: "Why does `int(3, 5)` raise this exception?" (if you printed `rn1` and `rn2` to get sample values).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more similar hints on asking a quality, focused question including code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator` variable hold a *string*. You have to use that string to determine the real operation to perform.

Something like that:

```
if operator == "+":
      realanswer = rn1 + rn2
elif operator == "-":
      realanswer = rn1 - rn2
elif operator == "/":
      realanswer = rn1 / rn2
elif operator == "*":
      realanswer = rn1 * rn2
else
      raise Exception('Bad operator {}'.format(operator))
```

Or better using the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
# top of your program
import operator

my_operators = { '+': operator.add,
                 '-': operator.sub,
                 '*': operator.mul,
                 '/': operator.div }

# ...
# and later:
realanswer = my_operators[operator](rn1,rn2)
```

Of course, in a real application, you would somehow have to deal with "invalid" user input. For example using proper exception handling. But this is an other story...

Answer (score 1):

First: Your `operator` is a string, not a function. You can't call `'/'(2,3)`, so if `operator=='/'`, you still can't call `operator(2,3)`.

Second: `int(rn1), int(rn2)` is how you convert two different numbers to integers, not `int(rn1, rn2)`.

Third: Return values from `randint()` are already integers, and don't need to be converted again.

---

I'd suggest converting your numbers to integers *as they're entered, only once*, rather than doing so on each reference. Thus:

```
minimum = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="Choose your minimum number"))
maximum = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="Choose your maximum number"))
operator = easygui.enterbox(msg="which operator would you like to use? X,/,+ or - ?", title="operator")
questions = int(easygui.enterbox(msg="enter your desired amount of questions"))

# Select a function associated with the chosen operator
operators = {
    '*': lambda a,b: a*b,
    '/': lambda a,b: a/b,
    '+': lambda a,b: a+b,
    '-': lambda a,b: a-b,
}
operator_fn = operators.get(operator)
if operator_fn is None:
    raise Exception('Unknown operator %r' % operator)

for a in range(questions):
    rn1 = randint(minimum, maximum))
    rn2 = randint(minimum, maximum))
    answer = int(easygui.enterbox("%s %s %s = ?" % (rn1, operator, rn2)))
    realanswer = operator_fn(rn1,rn2)
    if answer == realanswer:
        print "Correct"
    else:
        print 'Incorrect, the answer was', realanswer
```

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, I hope you'll forgive me for cribbing from the dict approach. (Though I can point at some of my own code that did the same thing, if my college projects from 15 years ago haven't been pruned from SourceForge).

Comment: No problem at all. I use the dict approach whenever I can, as it has kind of "declarative style" I like -- with the benefits to help writing clean error handling code -- and to usually ease maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

`operator` is just a string, you still need to write the code that makes it mean something. You could do something like:

```
if operator in ('+', 'add'):
    realanswer = rn1 + rn2
elif operator in ('-', 'subtract'):
    realanswer = rn1 - rn2
else:
    print operator, "is not valid"
```